# Multiple, remotely accessible dev sites on IIS 8 over SSL?

Tags: iis-8

I am trying to configure a remote server to host two or more development sites.  My current approach was:

Hostname: somedev.something.somethingelse.com

Desired site 1: dev1.somedev.something.somethingelse.com
Desired site 2: dev2.somedev.something.somethingelse.com

I modified my hosts file so that:

dev1 127.0.0.1
dev2 127.0.0.1

I created a wildcard SSL certificate for my domain, and configured the bindings to use that SSL certificate.

However, while on the box locally I can access my sites at the desired sites, how can I expose this such that I can browse remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will either need to use a public DNS server to point those DNS names to the server's public IP address, configure your existing DNS server to point those names to the IPs (if you have a DNS server), or modify the hosts file on the machines you want to access it to point those names to the server's IP address